# How to assign a protocol to my metro app (Win8.1)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I developed an app in Visual Studio 2012 and I want to give it a name for open it or launching from webBrowsers or Shortcuts created in my desktop like next examples:

- Music app: microsoftmusic:///
- News app: bingnews:///
- Video app: microsoftvideo:///

how to do get a name like all these

thanks for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a walk-through of how to add protocol activation to your app:

[How to Handle URI Activation (HTML Apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452686.aspx)

[How to Handle URL Activation (C#, VB, and C++ Apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779670.aspx)

Add the protocol in your app manifest and then write the code to handle activation from that protocol.

Comment: Thank you!!! it worked!!! but everytime I run my app from protocol name, it doesn't show splashScreen, how can I fix it???